# Calling Dataframe in a def function()

Tags: python-2.7

My dataframe is working well outside my function, one I call it inside I get this error:

> "Error while preprocessing DataFrame: Length of values does not match
>   length of index"

The code is, where g is a graph and data is the name of the dataframe:

```
def function(g, data):
  idx = 0
  var1 = []
  var2 = []
  for x in g.indegree():
    if x <=1:
      var_idx = data[3].values[idx]
      if var1_idx > var2_idx:
        var1.append(var1_idx)
      else:
        var1.append(var2_idx)
    idx+=1
  data[3] = var1
  dati[6] = var2
  data = data[[3,6]]
  grouped = data.groupby([3,6]).sum().reset_index() 
  return grouped
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added the code

Comment: Great, now you just need example of input with desired output :)

Comment: input : pd.read_csv("./data.txt", sep = "|", header = None)
output : error